# Python ImportError when running an installed script

Tags: python, import, installation, package

I have some trouble running my installed python scripts due to some import problems.

I have a package structure as follows:

```
MANIFEST.in
setup.py
bin/opal.py
bin/opal/
   /__init__.py
   /__init__.pyc
   /core.py
   /core.pyc        
   /io.py
   /file.py
   /import_limesurvey.py
   /dictionary.py
   /io.pyc
   /importer.pyc
   /data.py
   /rest.py
```

The rest.py has one class in it:

```
class OpalRestCommand:
  ...
```

The opal.py file uses this module in the following way:

```
import opal.rest
...
restCmd = opal.rest.OpalRestCommand()
```

This is the setup definition:

```
...
setup_args = get_kw(
    name=PACKAGE_NAME,
    version=VERSION,
    author=AUTHOR,
    author_email=AUTHOR_EMAIL,
    maintainer=MAINTAINER,
    maintainer_email=MAINTAINER_EMAIL,
    url=URL,
    license=LICENSE,
    description=DESCRIPTION,
    long_description=DESCRIPTION_LOG,
    platforms=PLATFORMS,
    packages = ['opal', 'opal.protobuf']
    package_dir = {'opal': 'bin/opal'}
    scripts=['bin/opal.py']
)

...

if __name__ == '__main__'
   # do some manipulation with argv
   apply(setup, (), setup_args)
```

When I install this on a client machine (MAC) and run the opal.py command, I always get the error:

```
 ImportError: No module name rest
```

However, if I create a test program that uses the rest module, I have no import problems. I  am a newbie to Python, I don't know if I should do something special for installed scripts! I assumed that the opal.py script should find my rest module the same way as the test program.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` in your `opal` directory?

Comment: Yes, I have '_____init_____.py' in my package folders.

Comment: Does `rest.py` get installed with your module?

Comment: Yes, it gets installed under the Python library folder and opal.py under '/usr/local/bin'. I was hoping no matter where opal.py is installed, I could still access the rest.py the same way I do in my test program. Cheers for the follow ups ;)

Comment: I think I see what you are doing.  Might I recommend keeping your `opal.py` in your `opal` directory and using [entry points](http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2010/01/06/zest-releaser-entry-points.html) from setuptools (or distribute).  That might take care of the issue.  Otherwise, it's difficult for me to diagnose because you haven't shown your entire `setup` call or your entire folder layout (for example `__init__.py`) was excluded.  Can you edit your post to include more of the `setup.py` script and your directory contents?

Comment: I added some more info to the original post. The above folder structure is used to build the package (tar.gz). I hope it is more clear. Thanks.

Comment: 1) When you run your test cases, where do you run them from?  2) Are you sure it is installed in the `site-packages` directory of your python library? 3) Are you using the same version of python when you install as when you try to run after installation? (check the `#!` line at the top of `opal.py`) 4) Does just `import opal` work after installation?  When you check, add `print opal.__file__` to find out where it is located.

Comment: Before I answer, My package is installed under /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ on my MAC under the expected folder 'opal'. The opal.py is copied to '/user/local/bin'.

Comment: Here is a recap of my response: Before I answer, My package is installed under /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ on my MAC under the expected folder 'opal'. The opal.py is copied to '/user/local/bin'. As for the questions: 1) From anywhere since the opal.py is in my PATH and the package is installed as the other packages are. 2) yes 3) Yes, I ran with --version, 4) unfortunately not! The print __opal.__file__ in opal.py shows the proper folder. Thanks for the helps Seth :)

Comment: When I was asking about the test cases, I meant the ones that you don't get import errors on (you mention in the 2nd to last paragraph of your post).  I'm assuming that you get import errors when you run `opal.py` since that's what the post is about :)

Comment: At the top of `opal.py` add `import sys; print sys.path`.  This will show if `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` is being searched.

Comment: One last thing, it's not common to see a module in `bin` in your source directory.  Try moving the `opal` directory to the same level as `setup.py` and changing `package_dir` to `{}`.  It might not help the problem but it's a more common way to organize your project.

Comment: My test program is run from a directory where I place my test programs (~/labs) but there is nothing special about it. I also placed the `sys.print` in both opal.py and test.py, `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` is found in both but in case of opal.py the list is longer. I also noticed that my package egg-info file is named UNKNOWN... I suspect this is not that important. Once I get to work, I will try your package organization suggestion. Thank you very much, you've been very patient.

Comment: I'm a bit concerned why `sys.path` is different between the two files.  That tells me something different might be going on between the two.  How are `opal.py` and `test.py` different?  If you copy `opal.py` to `~/labs` and run it there does it work?  If not, then the issue is with `opal.py` and not your installation.

Comment: Hi Seth, many thanks for all the help. The problem was the name of the stupid script. As I am a rookie in Python, I still am not sure why the name was the problem! I renamed the opal.py to opelcmd.py and now the sctipt runs correctly. I guess I have some more readings to do ;) I also wanted to credit you for all the help. May be you can copy all your comments as an answer and I can accept it. Cheers.

Comment: Before I make an answer, was `opal.py` in your `site-packages` directory as well as the `opal` directory?  If so, in my answer I will make a suggestion on how to resolve that and still have your script named `opal`.

Comment: No, it was copied to /usr/local/bin. All your suggestions were very useful, cheers for that. I will accept your answer once it's posted. My above suggestion- gathering all your above comments under one answer is not bad ;)

Answer (score 0):

I just spent some time coming to grips with this problem on my own project before I realized I was not properly respecting the python import path.

When the name of the script you are running matches the root of your namespace there will be namespace problems.  opal.py is conflicting with opal/**init**.py.  This can even happen when using setuptools as you are.

Assuming SITEPACKAGES=/usr/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages your package will be installed at $SITEPACKAGES/opal-$version.egg and your scripts will be installed in $SITEPACKAGES/opal-$version.egg/EGG-INFO/bin/opal.py with a file added to /usr/local/bin that loads the script that is placed in EGG-INFO/bin/.  When that script loads there is a small problem.

The python path will include $SITEPACKAGES/opal-$version.egg/EGG-INFO/bin/.  When the importer tries to import anything within opal it will import the script you are running and not the modules in $SITEPACKAGES/opal-$version.egg/opal/.  This is because of the collision between your script name and the namespace implemented in your package.

Either your package's namespace needs to change or the command line script name needs to change.